# Getting error when predicting Random forest AUC

Tags: r, random-forest, caret, auc, r-ranger

I am using the r package caret and ranger to develop a classifier to predict the risk of dying, but I am having trouble calculating AUC:

I am aware that I need to set probability = TRUE when training the model, however, I get an error saying:

'formal argument "probability" matched by multiple actual arguments' and I cant run the model.

My code:

```
set.seed(40)

control.data <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, sampling ="up", VerboseIter= TRUE)

rfGrid <- expand.grid(
.mtry=2:6,
.splitrule="gini",
.min.node.size=c(250,500))

fit.dataup <- train(mort_30 ~ C_SEX+V_AGE+Hemoglobin+Thrombocytes+Leukocytes+CRP,
data=data.train,
method="ranger",
max.depth=10,
num.trees=500,
trControl=control.data,
tuneGrid=rfGrid,
importance="impurity",
probability = TRUE,
verbose=TRUE)
```

Then i get this error message, when trying to run it:

```
Model fit failed for Fold01: mtry=2, splitrule=gini, min.node.size=500 Error in ranger::ranger(dependent.variable.name = ".outcome", data =x,: formal argument "probability" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your code here please?

Comment: yes, sorry. I am working on a remote server, that doesn't allow for me to copy it. But I will write it out manually.